# Getting titleForRow Using UIPicker from NSArray - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, uipicker

I'm trying to return the object from my array using a UIPickerViewDelegate below:

```
var myArr = NSArray()
```

Adding objects to my array

```
self.myArray = NSArray(objects: "Mr", "Mrs", "Miss", "Ms", "Dr", "Master", "Rev",
            "Fr", "Atty", "Prof", "Hon")
```

Here is my delegate

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    var string = NSString(coder: self.myArray.objectAtIndex(row) as NSCoder)
    return string
}
```

However this throws an exception. How do i do this simple task?

Comment: why are you using the coder: initialiser in your delegate method, you have an array of strings. Unless theres something you're not showing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based solely on your question, and assuming there's nothing relevant you haven't mentioned, get rid of the coder stuff:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return self.myArray.objectAtIndex(row) as NSString
}
```

Since this is a swift program, you should also probably not be using NSArray since that results in type ambiguity:

```
var myArr = ["Mr", "Mrs", "Miss", "Ms", "Dr", "Master", "Rev",
        "Fr", "Atty", "Prof", "Hon"]
```

And now your delegate method becomes even clearer:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return myArray[row]
}
```